# Stuck on scanning multiple beacon regions and getting notifications for each in background

Tags: iphone, swift, notifications, ibeacon, estimote

I'm attempting to scan just two ibeacon regions and get lock screen or background notifications.  Both regions consist of just one Estimote beacon for now.  My code is below for my app delegate, and at the moment I just receive notifications for the first beacon, but not the second.  I'm using the latest swift 2.2, Xcode 7.3.1 and working with an iPhone 4s with the latest iOS .  Portions of code that are 'boilerplate' and common are left out on purpose to shorten this question.

import CoreLocation
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, ESTBeaconManagerDelegate {

```
var app: BeacondoApp!
var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
var locationManager2: CLLocationManager!
let beaconManager = ESTBeaconManager()
let beaconManager2 = ESTBeaconManager()
var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {


    ESTConfig.setupAppID("xxxx", andAppToken: "xxxx")

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Alert, categories: nil))

    self.beaconManager.delegate = self
    self.beaconManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    beaconManager.avoidUnknownStateBeacons = true


    self.beaconManager2.delegate = self
    self.beaconManager2.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    beaconManager2.avoidUnknownStateBeacons = true



    self.beaconManager.startMonitoringForRegion(CLBeaconRegion(
        proximityUUID: NSUUID(UUIDString: "B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D")!,
        major: 28345, minor: 32093, identifier: "S Region"))


    self.beaconManager2.startMonitoringForRegion(CLBeaconRegion(
        proximityUUID: NSUUID(UUIDString: "C7F8D409-D559-4D48-B251-865941710A5D")!,
        major: 35148, minor: 41932, identifier: "P Region"))




    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self



    locationManager2 = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager2.delegate = self

    return true
}


func beaconManager(manager: AnyObject, didEnterRegion region: CLBeaconRegion) {

    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.alertBody =
    "Estimote S Entry Notification"
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().presentLocalNotificationNow(notification)
    print("Estimote S Entry Notification")
    }



func beaconManager(manager: AnyObject, didExitRegion region: CLBeaconRegion) {
    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.alertBody =
    "Estimote S Departure Notification"
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().presentLocalNotificationNow(notification)
    print("Estimote S Exit Notification")
    }



func beaconManager2(manager: AnyObject, didEnterRegion region: CLBeaconRegion) {

    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.alertBody =
    "Estimote P Entry Notification"
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().presentLocalNotificationNow(notification)
    print("Estimote P Entry Notification")
}



func beaconManager2(manager: AnyObject, didExitRegion region: CLBeaconRegion) {
    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.alertBody =
    "Estimote P Departure Notification"
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().presentLocalNotificationNow(notification)
    print("Estimote P Exit Notification")
}
```

}

Comment: Is there a reason you need two LocationManager instances?  I would try with one.

Comment: I'm told the device will only wake up once for each UUID in a region so if I want to use the device to wake up from background mode and send a notification to the user then I need two different regions and two different UUID's.

Comment: Yes, but I do not think you need or want two LocationManager instances.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions on how I can get two beacons sharing the same UUID provide separate entry and exit notifications without get in in the way of each other.